# Какие типы данных в Oracle соответсвуют типам WORD и DWORD?

Tags: типы-данных, oracle

Какие типы данных в Oracle соответсвуют типам WORD и DWORD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Второй ответ в гугле:

> DWORD - 32-bit unsigned integer.
>
> long or int.
>
> WORD - 16-bit unsigned integer.
>
> int or short.
>
> CHAR - 8-bit Windows (ANSI) character.
>
> byte.

[Thread: Data types](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1550283).